# Calculating the number of lines for each pair of origin/destination point - QGIS3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3

I have shapefile that looks like this:[image] I need to make a matrix (or just to add a couple of fields in the attribute table, something like the origin-destination matrix), which will have the number of links that go from each point to target point. I mean, I don't have physically point, just beginning and end of each line. For example, matrix/attribute table should look like this:

```
Target_point_coord     Point_coord_1    Point_coord_2  ...   Point_coord_N
  point_coord_1              0            15           ...     50
  point_coord_2             15             0           ...     2
         ......................................................
  point_coord_N             50             2                   0
```

this means that 15 lines from point 2 go to point 1, 50 lines from point N to point 1, etc. Or to be more clear, this also means that 15 lines have started at point_coordinates_2 and ended at target_point_1, and so on. The lines are not directed so that I have for the row 2 that 15 lines from point_coord_1 go to Point_coord_2.

I approximately have about 150 points and I also have the list of that points in the CSV file, if it's matter.

Is there is a way to do this in QGIS or PyQGIS? And if it is, how?

Comment: Is your data a single layer of line geometry class where each element is exactly one line segment? What is the tolerance for two points to be the same point entity?

Comment: Some of the lines have more than one segment, but I need to look just from the last point to the next one. I can solve that with dissolving (turning all multilines in more single lines).  I have around 150 points and each line finishes/starting in one of exactly these points. I know that for sure because this shapefile was created from that intersection points. I have also the list of coordinates of that points in CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in not direct solution, but some workaround.

1) With *Extract vertices* (from processing) You will get all vertices from the all the lines with all the data and also index of points along the line.

[image]

OR

2) With *Extract specific vertices* when only the start and end is important, you can extract vertices 0 (start point) and -1, (end point)

[image]

After that make some join by location action, to get desired output. And in final step, use *Points to path* to convert points to new lines.